# Model validation error handling in Rails with GraphQL, passing as a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

So traditional REST API has the following model validations back in JSON hash like:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "last_name": [
     "can't be blank"
   ],
    "email_address": [
     "is not valid"
   ]
 }
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I get the errors hashed like in the following:
[Errors and Non Nullability](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/draft/#sec-Errors-and-Non-Nullability)

Right now my current errors are displaying as:

```
{
"errors": [
{
  "message": "Field 'userCreate' is missing required arguments: lastName, authProvider",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 2,
      "column": 3
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "mutation user",
    "userCreate"
  ]
}
]}
```

Is there a recommended way to hash these errors in Rails?

Here's the GraphQL Controller per request:

```
class GraphqlController < ApplicationController
  def execute
    variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
    query = params[:query]
    operation_name = params[:operationName]
    context = {
      # Query context goes here, for example:
      session: session,
      current_user: current_user
    }
    result = BackendSchema.execute(
      query,
      variables: variables,
      context: context,
      operation_name: operation_name)
    render json: result
  end

  private

  def current_user
    # session isn't initialized unless written to
    session['init'] = true
    return unless session[:token]
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.byteslice(0..31))
    token = crypt.decrypt_and_verify session[:token]
    user_id = token.gsub('user-id:', '').to_i
    User.find_by id: user_id
  rescue ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
    Rails.logger.debug 'Invalid signature'
  end

  # Handle form data, JSON body, or a blank value
  def ensure_hash(ambiguous_param)
    case ambiguous_param
    when String
      if ambiguous_param.present?
        ensure_hash(JSON.parse(ambiguous_param))
      else
        {}
      end
    when Hash, ActionController::Parameters
      ambiguous_param
    when nil
      {}
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Unexpected parameter: #{ambiguous_param}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please paste the controller code

Comment: Added the GraphQL Controller